# How to get the Year in between two dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have

**leave table**

```
EmpNo
EmpName
LeaveStart
LeaveEnd
```

I want to show the leave taken by year and i used `datediff(dd,LeaveStart,LeaveEnd)`

it will shows the no. of days have taken.

but i want to show yearly wise.

**E.g**

```
2014 - 10 days

2015 - 16 days
```

how & where i can use year function becoz have leavestart & leaveend
suppose if employee taken a leave

```
LeavStart- 28-Dec-2015

LeaveEnd - 05-Jan-2016
```

then result should

```
2015 - 4 days

2016 - 5 days
```

then how to use query.

please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
SELECT Year(LeaveStart),YEAR(LeaveEnd),DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(LeaveStart), Max(LeaveEnd)) 
FROMtbl_Subject_OrderAssignedDetails
GROUP BY Year(LeaveStart),YEAR(LeaveEnd)
```